# How do you make a horizontal loop cut?

Tags: looping

I was watching a tutorial series on YouTube and at 5:11 he made a few loop cuts that are horizontal. How did he do this?

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnPkrxz4AQQ

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html *"After the tool is activated, move the cursor over a desired edge. The cut to be made is marked with a magenta colored line as you move the mouse over the various edges."*

Answer (score 1):

1. Initiate loop-cut mode by hitting Crtl + R
2. While you are still in that mode, scroll your mouse wheel (up or down) / Page UP - Page Down buttons work as well. Or if you have some specific numbers of parallel running loops in your mind, you can make use of the numeric keys as well.